# Libgdx game crashes

Tags: java, crash, libgdx, box2d

My libgdx game crashes sometimes. I have no Idea why, so I don't think it is worth posting code yet, before knowing where it is comoing from. I am running the game on Windows. Here is the console output:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:144), pid=12252, tid=14156
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\...\assets\hs_err_pid12252.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
# Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where could this error come from? Could it have something to do with Box2d, Shapes, Bodies...?

Comment: "An error report file with more information is saved as: ..." Perhaps that is helpful. Have you read that?

Comment: I have opened it but I dont understand anything.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/yh4kKV3w

Comment: Now I got an other error related to a b2Body: http://pastebin.com/dnkJZBvt

Comment: Here is the code where I create the bodies. It gets a list of lists that contain Vector2's and creates bodies with rotated square shapes along the points (like ShapeRenderer.RectLine).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4TPBnk5C

Comment: and it also just crashed with this: 
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)